# Adding Multiple Existing Security Groups to EC2 using AWS-CDK (python)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Trying to add multiple existing security groups to a new ec2. It does not seem to work. If it is one group in the globalsg it works.

```
globalsg ={
(ec2.SecurityGroup.from_security_group_id(self, "sg01", security_group_id = "sg-xb9b")),
(ec2.SecurityGroup.from_security_group_id(self, "sg02", security_group_id = "sg-x211"))
}
#Webserver 01
    web01 = ec2.Instance(
        self,
        "web01Id",
        instance_type = ec2.InstanceType(instance_type_identifier=variables["inst_type"]),
        instance_name = "A.APP.PR01",
        machine_image = ec2.MachineImage.generic_linux(
                {variables["region"]: linux_ami}
        ),            
        vpc=vpc,
        vpc_subnets = vpc_priv_use1a,
        user_data = ec2.UserData.custom(user_data),
        security_group= [globalsg]
    )
```

Here is the error that I get
jsii.errors.JSIIError: Expected object reference, got [[{"$jsii.byref":"@aws-cdk/core.Resource@10052"}]]

Answer (score 1):

Define globalsg as a list, get rid of the dict brackets and don't wrap it in a list when you reference it.  Something like this:

```
globalsg = [
    ...
]

...

security_group=globalsg[0]
)

web01.add_security_group(globalsg[1])
```

The instance takes a single security group in the constructor.  Then you can call add_security_group to add more.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_ec2/Instance.html#aws_cdk.aws_ec2.Instance.add_security_group

Comment: thanks.  I tried your suggestion, however it still is not working 
globalsg = [ 
            ec2.SecurityGroup.from_security_group_id(self, "sg01", security_group_id = "sg-xb9b"),
            ec2.SecurityGroup.from_security_group_id(self, "sg02", security_group_id = "sg-xb211")       
        ] 

security_group = globalsg 

This is the error.

jsii.errors.JSIIError: Expected object reference, got [{"$jsii.byref":"@aws-cdk/core.Resource@10052"},{"$jsii.byref":"@aws-cdk/core.Resource@10053"}]      
Subprocess exited with error 1

Comment: See edit, I added more to the answer.  Constructor takes a single security group